# Bottle GET throws a 404 error despite route

Tags: python, bottle

I'm new to Bottle. I've written an application with the following route:

```
@route('/search?<querystring>')
```

Yet, a GET request to the URL

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/search?query=test
```

throws a 404 error. It's probably to do with the question mark in the URL, but I can't figure out how to fix this problem. Making the querystring variable bigger so as to include the question mark doesn't work, since it only appears to catch the characters leading up to the question mark. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The querystring is not part of the route. The route is just `/search`, and the query string can be accessed from [`request.query`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.query).

Answer (score 1):

Bottle's route will only match the URI *path*.  I think what you want is something more along these lines:

```
from bottle import request

@route('/search')
def search():
    query = request.params.get('query')
    # foo = request.params.get('foo')   # and so on
    return 'Your query value was: {}'.format(query)
```

(As @DanielRoseman correctly pointed out, you can use [request.query](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.query) instead of [request.params](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.params), but I generally use the latter.)